# How to use local routing with Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-routing

I have an app and I need to do some local routing.

I have attached the file structure as an image

[image]

What I want to do is when I click on a button in the manage account it then navigates to accountdetailed.

Currently I have the routing in the app-routing.module.ts like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule),
    canLoad: [AutoLoginGuard] // Check if we should show the introduction or forward to inside
  },
  {
    path: 'nav',
    loadChildren: () => import('./sidenav/sidenav.module').then(m => m.SidenavPageModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard] // Secure all child pages
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'accountdetailed/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./manageaccount/accountdetailed/accountdetailed.module').then( m => m.AccountdetailedPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'manageaccount',
    loadChildren: () => import('./manageaccount/manageaccount.module').then( m => m.ManageaccountPageModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and here is my manageaccount code:

html:

```
<ion-list id="settingList" class="ion-no-padding">
    <ion-item color="dark" id="yourDetailsBtn"  (click)="showDetail('details', 'yourDetailsBtn')" button>
      <ion-label class="white-text">Your Details</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

manageaccount.page.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {IonAccordionGroup, NavController} from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manageaccount',
  templateUrl: './manageaccount.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manageaccount.page.scss'],
})
export class ManageaccountPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(IonAccordionGroup, {static: true}) accordionGroup: IonAccordionGroup;

  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  logAccordionValue() {
    console.log(this.accordionGroup.value);
  }

  closeAccordion() {
    this.accordionGroup.value = undefined;
  }

  showDetail(type, id) {

    alert(id);
    console.log(id);

    this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['accountdetailed', id]);

  }
}
```

manageaccount-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ManageaccountPage } from './manageaccount.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ManageaccountPage
  },
  {
    path: 'accountdetailed/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./accountdetailed/accountdetailed.module').then( m => m.AccountdetailedPageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ManageaccountPageRoutingModule {}
```

So when I click on Your details button and it calls showDetail() method, how do I make it use the manageaccount-routing.module.ts instead of the main app routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `accountdetailed/:id` route from the app-routing to manageaccount-routing, and set them both to have the same prefix:

```
www.angulat-app.com/manageaccount - loads the manage account 
www.angulat-app.com/manageaccount/accountdetailed/id - loads the account details
```

Inside the app-routing, remove the `'accountdetailed/:id'` path:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule),
    canLoad: [AutoLoginGuard] // Check if we should show the introduction or forward to inside
  },
  {
    path: 'nav',
    loadChildren: () => import('./sidenav/sidenav.module').then(m => m.SidenavPageModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard] // Secure all child pages
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'manageaccount',
    loadChildren: () => import('./manageaccount/manageaccount.module').then( m => m.ManageaccountPageModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Then differentiate between your routes inside manageaccount-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', // empty route (i.e. /manageaccount/ would load only manageaccount
    component: ManageaccountPage
  },
  {
    path: 'accountdetailed/:id', // i.e. /manageaccount/accountdetailed/:id
    loadChildren: () => import('./accountdetailed/accountdetailed.module').then( m => m.AccountdetailedPageModule)
  },
  
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And of course, don't forget to change the router navigation in your `showDetail(type, id)` function:

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['manageaccount/accountdetailed', id]);
```